# Is the dash a special character in shiny IDs?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm attempting to use a conditionalPanel to hide certain ui elements. I discovered that using a "-" in the id of the input element used in the condition statement causes the condtionalPanel to break. Is this expected behavior? I had thought the "-" character was allowable in shiny IDs.

Working example (remove "-" from 'file-Opt' and 'input.file-Opt' to enable the conditional panel to work again.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fileInput('file', 'Choose file to upload',
    accept = c(
      'text/csv',
      'text/comma-separated-values',
      'text/tab-separated-values',
      'text/plain',
      '.csv',
      '.tsv'
    )
  ),
  checkboxInput('file-Opt', "Show advanced file options", FALSE),
  tags$hr(),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = 'input.file-Opt == true',
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE)
  ) # conditionalPanel close
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Well, the condition parameter needs to be a valid javascript expression and the `-` symbol is not allowed variable names. So `input.file-Opt` is interpreted as "input.file minus Opt" which isn't what you want. You could probably do `input["file-Opt"]` but it would be better just to avoid dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not recommended to use special JavaScript characters such as a period `.` in the input id's, but if you do use them anyway, for example, `inputId = "foo.bar"`, you will have to use `input["foo.bar"]` instead of `input.foo.bar` to read the input value.
I guess the same goes for "-".

Source:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html

Comment: Thank you, that saved me some headache! This is particularly useful when referring to elements created within UI modules, as Shiny prefixes the element ids with the namespace name and a dash.